# location of Python libraries installed

Tags: python-3.x, installation, site-packages

I have installed Python 3.8 in my machine (windows 10). I can see it is installed in following locations, and my Python programs are running fine, after adding these locations in PATH variable.

```
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38
C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38
```

My questions:

1. Why is it installed in a local directory as well as a roaming directory?
2. In which directory I can find the source code of the functions like list append(), list insert(). I have tried looking for them in the site-package directory, but it has a huge number of sub-directories, and unable to figure out where exactly to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer two of your questions:

1. you can find the source code in:
   C:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Lib>
2. you can run 'where' in WINDOWS terminal to find out which Python version installed. Also run these Python snippet to confirm:

```py
    >>> import os
    >>> import sys
    >>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    'C:\\Users\\<User>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39-32'
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The lib directory has huge number of elements and sub-directories within it. If I want to see the source code of function insert used to add elements in list : list_name.insert(index, element), where can I find the exact location?

Comment: You may check out this file -
 https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c

Comment: (line 294 - insert)

Comment: @Monalisha Bhowmik - are you able to find it?

Comment: Thank you, I got it. I was wondering if these sources are there in our Python library installed in our machines as well.

Comment: Yes. It’s in.  If you find the post is helpful, please accept and upvote it? Thanks